# Variables in Javascript object names

Tags: jquery, json, variables, object

I'd like to know whether it is possible to use variables in object names in jquery.

This is my code :

```
$.post("sp.php",function(data){
var val=data+'fname'; 
alert(val); \\ i basically want to perform alert(data.fname)
},"json");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to access the "fname" property off the data object? If so you can just do one of the following:

```
var val = data.fname;
```

or

```
var val = data["fname"];
```

Comment: The second answer : var val = data["houseno"]; works great for variable object names
Thanks a ton :D

Answer (score 1):

That’s perfectly legitimate Javascript yes. It probably would have been quicker to just try it rather than write a post here though.

Comment: It does work, it's valid JS. What **won't** work is that you're manipulating `data` with each pass, and that's (potentially) a collection of objects or values. However, I now see that you've amended your original post to state that you wish to access an element _within_ `data` in which case that's a different question (which Clayton has answered).